# Cassandra backup system keyspaces

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 node cassandra cluster and I have a script which backup all of the keyspaces, but when it comes to restore on fresh cluster, data keyspaces restored correctly, but system_* keyspaces not.
So it is necessary to backup system keyspaces in cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to backup the keyspace `system_schema` at the same time, as it will contain the definition of keyspaces, tables, and columns. The other `system*` keyspaces should be left untouched.

Comment: thank you! but what if i want restore data to the existing cluster, because for example business data lost, do i need to restore system keyspaces? thank you

Comment: Restoring data on an existing cluster, especially in a production environment, will cause an outage. All the information that was recorded after the backup was taken may be lost after the restore over the existing cluster is done. For that use case, we usually create a new cluster identified with the suffix "RESTORED" that runs in parallel to the production cluster, that will allow us to compare data, and if needed, export/import only the records affected.

Comment: While restoring the cluster, the only system* related keyspace that is overwritten is `system_schema`, this will guarantee that the cluster will have the same characteristics when the backup was created; this has resulted useful especially with backups that are not recent.

Comment: We have our clusters in the cloud (AWS), which facilitates the provision of new instances; for bare metal instances I understand the pain and costs  of having a parallel cluster running, depending on your use case and the characteristics of your data, it may be worthy to use a temporary Cassandra as a Service instance, there are multiple options, as you will need it for a short time

Comment: Thank you! do you know about that? https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa

Answer (score 0):

Fresh cluster makes own setup like token ranges etc based on configurations.you can restore the cluster on new cluster but you need to create schema and configuration same as old cluster. There is many ways to take backup and restore procedure based on requirements as below:-
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupRestore.html